# Cannot access installed python packages in Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container that requires a couple Python packages to be installed. I added some commands to install them, but the packages are not available in the container. I *think* I'm added them wrong, is there a certain way I need to copy over what was installed? Any help appreciated.

Specifically, I should be able to run `lottie.py` in my container after installing it, but it does not exist, nor does pip3 even though the install is successful.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine AS builder

COPY . /go/src/matterbridge
RUN apk --no-cache add go git
WORKDIR /go/src/matterbridge
RUN go build -mod vendor -o /bin/matterbridge

FROM python:3
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir lottie cairosvg
RUN apt-get install libcairo2-dev

FROM alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates mailcap
COPY --from=builder /bin/matterbridge /bin/matterbridge
RUN mkdir /etc/matterbridge \
  && touch /etc/matterbridge/matterbridge.toml \
  && ln -sf /matterbridge.toml /etc/matterbridge/matterbridge.toml
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/matterbridge", "-conf", "/etc/matterbridge/matterbridge.toml"]
```

Comment: You don't do anything with your second `FROM` stage, so those layers get thrown away by your next FROM.

Comment: @SiHa how would I copy over what I installed so it's accessible in my next FROM?

Comment: Your final image doesn't even have Python, so you'll struggle to run anything you do copy over. Why not just use an alpine-python image, do the pip installs, and then copy the stuff from the builder stage - no need for a third FROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was given help in the comments that I'm not copying anything over from the Python image. I was able to find `python:alpine` and use that in my config below

```
FROM alpine AS builder

COPY . /go/src/matterbridge
RUN apk --no-cache add go git
WORKDIR /go/src/matterbridge
RUN go build -mod vendor -o /bin/matterbridge

FROM python:alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates mailcap
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl
RUN apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .pynacl_deps build-base python3-dev py3-pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir lottie cairosvg
COPY --from=builder /bin/matterbridge /bin/matterbridge
RUN mkdir /etc/matterbridge \
  && touch /etc/matterbridge/matterbridge.toml \
  && ln -sf /matterbridge.toml /etc/matterbridge/matterbridge.toml
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/matterbridge", "-conf", "/etc/matterbridge/matterbridge.toml"]
```